# Why does non-abelianity implies a single coupling constant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lie-algebra, grand-unification

Why does a theory described by a non-abelian group has only a single coupling constant $g$?
While on the other hand in an abelian theory, as Electromagnetism, each charged particle has its own charge with which its interacts with the gauge fields?

In [Grand Unified Theory by P. Langacker](http://lss.fnal.gov/conf/C810824/p823.pdf), its is mentioned it the beginning of section III that model described by a group
$$G= G_1\times \cdots \times G_1 \times D ,$$
where $D$ a discrete subgroup that permutes identical factors $G_1$,
is also described by a single coupling constant. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Comments to the question (v2):

1. For a [reductive Lie group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductive_group) of the form $G=G_1\times \ldots \times G_n$, where each factor $G_i$ is either [simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group) or $U(1)$, then there exists an independent coupling constant $g_i$ for each factor $G_i$. In particular, a non-abelian Lie group can have more than one coupling constant.
2. The article *Grand Unified Theory* by P. Langacker is talking about the case where a discrete subgroup $D$ permutes *identical* factors $G_1$. Then there is no room for individual coupling constants, only a single common coupling constant for all $G_1$-copies.